# WWW::Mechanize- Select from drop down list

Tags: html, perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to use WWW::Mechanize to select an option from a drop-down menu. Here is the code I have right now (only the part with selecting from the drop down menu):

```
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $url = 'http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgBlat?command=start';
my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new();
  $browser->get($url);
    $browser->select('db', 'hg38');
    $browser->submit();
```

The selection does not work.

Here is the HTML for this drop-down menu from the site where I've manually selected the desired option:

```
<select name="db"> = $0
     <option selected value="hg38">Dec. 2013 (GRch38/hg38)</option>
     <option value="hg19">Feb. 2009 (GRch17/hg19)</option>
     <option value="hg18">Mar. 2006 (NCBI36/hg18)</option>
     <option value="hg17">May 2004 (NCBI35/hg17)</option>
     <option value="hg16">July 2003 (NCBI34/hg16)</option>
</select>
```

How can I use Mech to select the option? The url for the website in question is 'http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgBlat?command=start'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ***always*** `use strict` at the top of every Perl program you write, especially before asking for help with your code. It would have revealed the problem immediately

Your `WWW::Mechanize` object is in `$browser`, but you have called `$mech->select`. `$mech` hasn't been defined so you are getting an error message saying that `select` can't be called on an undefined value

Comment: ah whoops, should've used strict. However, even after changing $mech to $browser, the selection still isn't made. There is no error, but I had my code spit out the URL after pressing submit elsewhere on the page and the result was that the drop-down selection still does not work.

Comment: @AdityaJ.: Use `$browser->dump_forms` to see the status of the forms on the page, so that you can check whether your selection has worked. You may need to use one of the form selection methods so that `select` knows which form to work on.